# UIView going completely black based on colour of UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel

I'm having an issue so strange I can't properly believe it.

I have a UIView that is segued to from a list of cells. I added a label to the cell and linked it and everything. Now, when I tap on the cell the resulting view that is opened is completely black, *except* for one UILabel.

I changed the colour of the UILabel to try and debug it a bit more.

I found some interesting things. The red slider must be 254, and the blue/green slider must be 23 or 22 for the view to display properly.

Turns out that the order of the sliders can be changed. Green at 254 worked with the others at 22.

I literally have no idea what is going on, so if anyone has any semblance of an idea, please say.

Comment: Show you code. Remember that if you use `colorWithRed:green:blue:`, it uses values between 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: I'm using the colour picker in the Interface Builder. There is no code.

Comment: can you post a screenshot showing the linking process in your storyboard? also, how you linked the UIlabel?

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the relevant labels and views: http://i.imgur.com/5GNBwp5.png

Comment: can you check if you have set the background color to black in the interface builder, for the topmost view in the detailed view controller?

Comment: Oh wow, that worked! If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct